In outlook, how to properly display incoming internet-style quoted messages
I send my messages using 'text' and old school 'internet-style' quoting in Thunderbird, like




I have a question





I know the answer



I have another question

Sorry, I don't know that answer

Clients with outlook (desktop) are complaining about the layout in their e-mail client. Apparently all text is shown unquoted.
Where are the settings to change that behaviour ? I don't have outlook, and I can't find it in the microsoft online documentation.
Note: this is about reading incoming messages, not composing outgoing messages.

How did you create old school 'internet-style' quoting?

Usually just by clicking 'reply' in thunderbird. Sometimes, I do 'paste as quotation' or I write the >> quotes myself.

As i know, we can only reply with inline comments within the original message text:
Reply with inline comments within the original message text


THank you, but my question was about reading incoming messages, not composing outgoing messages.

If so, it's suggested that you could log in to web mail to check if all format is displayed correct.
